# Program shutsdown after scanf for char*

Tags: c, string, crash, scanf

I've been trying to reciece a path to a picture from the user, if I type "img1.png"(the picture is in the directory of the project) it wont work, even if I enter "./images/img1.png"(again the picture is now in the images folder which is in the same directory as the project.
the only typing that wont collapse but obviously isnt right is ".img1.png" but then i wont get the source Im needed.
all the methods works fine because before that I recieve few images from the images folder as mentiond before. 
I'll appriciate your help, im trying to figure this out for almost 3 days.

```
    char query[1024]
    int** queryHist;
    double** querySift;
    queryHist = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*bins);
    printf("Enter a query image or # to terminate:\n");
    fflush(NULL);
    scanf("%s",query);
    printf("----%s",query);
    sleep(10);
    if(strcmp("#", query) == 0){
        printf(EXIT_MSG);
        fflush(NULL);
        free(nFeatures);
        free(hist);
        void free(void*);
        return 0;
    }
    queryHist =  spGetRGBHist(query, bins);
    querySift =  spGetSiftDescriptors(query, fet, &queryFeatures);
    bestHistsdis = bestHistogramDistances(queryHist, hist, bins, num);
```

bins is from the user. my problem is not even getting to queryHist/querySift. I've tried already to print query after it is recieved from the user but the program wont print it and collapse, even tried to use 5 seconds of sleep in case It just doesnt have the time to print the query and still collapse without printing but still waits the time

P.S All of the vars are declared on the top of the method, I've coopied them so they will be here
P.S.2 I'm only allowed to use methods from c

Comment: what won't work? Have you verified that `query` contains the string you type in? If so, then what are `spGetRGBHist` and `spGetSiftDescriptors` doing? Are those your functions? Do they both fail? Probably would be helpful to see the code for those. What is `bins`?

Comment: What is `void free(void*);` doing in the middle of all that code?

Comment: And I'm afraid we cannot help you until you post a [mcve].

Comment: bins is a number typed from the user as well.. I tryed to print query after getting it from the user but it never reaches there, it just collapse and thats why I've posted the problem is in scanf

Comment: I don't know what is your platform, but `fflush(NULL)` is probably useless.

Comment: [tag:c] has not methods, only functions.

Comment: Debugger..................